How to filter documents based on a list of metadata in LangChain's Chroma VectorStore?
I'm working with LangChain's Chroma VectorStore, and I'm trying to filter documents based on a list of document names.
I have a list of document names as follows:
lst = ['doc1', 'doc2', 'doc3']

I also have doc_name metadata in my VectorStore. Currently, I’m using the following code to retrieve documents:
base_retriever = chroma_db.as_retriever(search_kwargs={'k': 10})

However, I’m not sure how to modify this code to filter documents based on my list of document names. Could anyone guide me on how to achieve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

# Define your list of document names
lst = ['doc1', 'doc2', 'doc3']

# Create a filter dictionary to filter by document names
filter_dict = {"name": {"$in": lst}}

# Modify the as_retriever method to include the filter in search_kwargs
base_retriever = chroma_db.as_retriever(search_kwargs={'k': 10, 'filter': filter_dict})

# Now you can use the retriever to search with the filter applied
query = "your search query"
results = base_retriever.invoke(query)
for result in results:
    print(result)


To filter documents based on multiple lists of metadata in LangChain's Chroma VectorStore, you can use the $and or $or operators to combine multiple filter conditions. Here's an example:
from langchain_community.vectorstores.chroma import Chroma

# Define your lists of metadata
name_list = ['doc1', 'doc2', 'doc3']
author_list = ['Alice', 'Bob']
published_list = [True]

# Create filter dictionaries for each list
name_filter = {"name": {"$in": name_list}}
author_filter = {"author": {"$in": author_list}}
published_filter = {"published": {"$in": published_list}}

# Combine filters using $and or $or operators
combined_filter = {
    "$and": [
        name_filter,
        author_filter,
        published_filter
    ]
}

# Create the retriever with the combined filter
base_retriever = chroma_db.as_retriever(search_kwargs={'k': 10, 'filter': combined_filter})

# Perform the query
query = "your search query"
results = base_retriever.invoke(query)

# Print the results
for result in results:
    print(result)

